# How convert "object" to numeric values including Nan

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nan

I have this data for many years, and need to plot error graph for different years, 1993 was selected with

```
fm93 = fmm[(fmm.Year == 1993)]
```

then the fm93 data frame is

```
Year    moB  m1     std1    co1 min1    max1    m2S   std2S co2S    min2S   max2S
1993    1   296.42  18.91   31  262.4   336      --   --   --       --      --
1993    2   280.76  24.59   28  239.4   329.3    --  --      --   --    --
1993    3   271.41  19.16   31  236.4   304.8   285.80  20.09   20  251.6   319.7
1993    4   287.98  22.52   30  245.9   341 296.75  21.77   27  261.1   345.7
1993    5   287.05  30.79   30  229.2   335.7   300.06  27.64   24  249.5   351.8
1993    6   288.65  11.29   4   275.9   301.9   263.70  73.40   7   156.5   361
1993    7   280.11  36.01   12  237 363 302.67  26.39   22  262.9   377.1
1993    8   296.51  34.55   31  234.8   372.9   305.85  39.95   28  234.1   417.9
1993    9   321.31  34.54   25  263.8   396 309.01  42.52   29  205.9   403.2
1993    10  315.80  8.63    2   309.7   321.9   288.65  35.86   31  230.9   345.4
1993    11  288.26  24.07   30  231.4   322.8   297.99  23.81   28  238 336.5
1993    12  296.87  18.31   31  257.6   331.5   303.02  20.02   29  265.7   340.7
```

When I try to plot moB,m1 with err std1 appear the error

```
ValueError: err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 or 2xN array-like ]
```

That is because the values are "object"..

```
array([[1993, 1, '296.42', '18.91', '31', '262.4', '336', '--', '--', '--',
    '--', '--'],
   [1993, 2, '280.76', '24.59', '28', '239.4', '329.3', '--', '--',
    '--', '--', '--'],
   [1993, 3, '271.41', '19.16', '31', '236.4', '304.8', '285.80',
    '20.09', '20', '251.6', '319.7'],
   [1993, 4, '287.98', '22.52', '30', '245.9', '341', '296.75',
    '21.77', '27', '261.1', '345.7'],
   [1993, 5, '287.05', '30.79', '30', '229.2', '335.7', '300.06',
    '27.64', '24', '249.5', '351.8'],
   [1993, 6, '288.65', '11.29', '4', '275.9', '301.9', '263.70',
    '73.40', '7', '156.5', '361'],
   [1993, 7, '280.11', '36.01', '12', '237', '363', '302.67', '26.39',
    '22', '262.9', '377.1'],
   [1993, 8, '296.51', '34.55', '31', '234.8', '372.9', '305.85',
    '39.95', '28', '234.1', '417.9'],
   [1993, 9, '321.31', '34.54', '25', '263.8', '396', '309.01',
    '42.52', '29', '205.9', '403.2'],
   [1993, 10, '315.80', '8.63', '2', '309.7', '321.9', '288.65',
    '35.86', '31', '230.9', '345.4'],
   [1993, 11, '288.26', '24.07', '30', '231.4', '322.8', '297.99',
    '23.81', '28', '238', '336.5'],
   [1993, 12, '296.87', '18.31', '31', '257.6', '331.5', '303.02',
    '20.02', '29', '265.7', '340.7']], dtype=object)
```

I try convert this data with

```
fm93_1 = fm93.astype('float64', raise_on_error = False)
```

But the problem remain.... How can convert Nan values ('--') or ignore to plot my results? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you should try to plot a sample of data after the '--' to see if a plot can be generated. You can try:

```
# This should plot from row 3 onwards, omitting row 1 and 2
df.iloc[3:].plot()
```

---

Assuming '--' is the problem, you can [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with np.NaN. NaN values are not plotted.

```
df.replace('--', np.NaN, inplace=True)
df.plot()
```

---

Another way is to select df that does not contain '--':

```
mask = df[df == '--'].any(axis=1) # Check if row contains '--'
valid_indexes = df[mask == False].index # Return index for rows w/o '--'

df.iloc[valid_indexes].plot()
```

Comment: With the first suggestion the error: AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'convert_objects' appear